# Kafka lag on Prometheus - wedge shaped

Tags: apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, lag, strimzi

i've Strimzi Kafka installed on Kubernetes(GKE) & i'm using Kafka Exporter to get the Kafka lag for consumer group.

The python code uses AIOKafka clients (Consumer/Producer), picks up data from Kafka topic and does some processing.
I'm using Kafka exporter to get the Kafka lag for the consumer group,
and I see a strange wedge-shaped graph every 6 hours i.e. the Kafka lag increases to 2k every 6 hours and then goes down to 0 or -ve value. (screenshot attached)[image: kafka-lag-wedge-shaped]

Pls note : Data is flowing into the topic at a constant rate, and is processed immediately - so, the data in the topic does not wedge shaped characteristic

PromQL query used:

```
sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup=~"$consumergroup",topic="topic"}) by (consumergroup, topic)
```

Any ideas on why the kafka lag is behaving this way ?
Also, why does the kafka lag show -ve values as well ?

How do i debug/fix this ?

tia!

Additional Info:

autocommit is enabled (maybe need to do manual commit ?)
__consumer_offsets has 50 partitions

Comment: What is the throughput of the topic? Do you see the same pattern if you split it further by partition (are all partitions showing the same pattern)?

Comment: @roby - yes, all 3 partitions have the same pattern

Comment: @KaranAlang what is the size of the messages produced to Kafka?